# Manejo de Apps que logean por API Rest en Elasticsearch

Tags: api, rest, elasticsearch

¡Hola! Necesito ayuda con el resto del esquema de API.

Quiero que mi programa envíe los datos a Elastic, pero que se puede ver como en este ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan, NGINX registra dos tipos de Logs.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto? En el Json que acompaño, ¿tengo que agregar algo?

```
{
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss,SSSZ"
        },
        "app": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "type": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "runner": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "message": {
            "type": "text"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: Para esto, en general se usa [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html), de manera que este último tome los datos de nginx y los inserte en elastic

Comment: @Emeeus eso lo entiendo, el tema es que no es NGINX lo que quiero registrar si no un Log de WSO2 que esta factorizado de una forma tal que relevo datos de Log específicos. Entonces, para que se entienda de que aplicación saque estos Logs, quiero especificarlo tal como se muestra en esta captura que compartí y no termino de entender si es que tengo que configurar algo en el JSON de INDEX o Algo en Kibana. Vos me podras ayudar?

Comment: Si indexas dos campos mas, "nginx.error" y "nginx.access" con sus correspondientes valores, seguro puedas hacer un gráfico como el de la imágen. El problema no está en la definición del índice, sino en la ingesta, por eso mencioné logstash. Osea, aunque cambies el índice, no vas a ver reflejado nada hasta no cambiar la ingesta de datos.

Comment: Kibana en este sentido no tendría influencia tampoco, es decir, todo depende de como se ingresan los datos.  Todo esto si no mal entendí el problema.

Comment: @Emeeus, excelente me fuiste super claro. En todo caso, en el json que especifique mas arriba, sabrias explicarme como aplicarlo con ese ejemplo?, osea, creo dos matrices (app.error y app.warn) y esto seria suficiente como para que kibana detecte de que estoy hablando tal cual se ve en la grafica?